# Append or create a file, in one command?

Tags: bash

Very simple task: grab an output and redirect it to a file, using shell.

Now, I need to create the file if it does not exist, or if it exist, I need to append data

If I use `output > file.txt` I get data overwritten at each access. Not what I want.
If I use `output >> file.txt` I get an error, because shell is trying to access the file while, I need it to create it first (it does not exist yet).

Is there a way to say in one line to create it, if the file doesn't exist, and append data or append only if the file does exist already?

I can just do that using an if-else (if file exist use >> otherwise use >), and I would like to avoid to complicate my code, if there is an easier way.

Comment: Use `>>`.  If the file doesn't exist, it'd be created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to create or append to a file in `bash`, you can use `>>`.

```
echo "sample text" >> sample_file
echo "append text" >> sample_file
```

Comment: cat "sample_file" >> "sample_file2"